# Add values the the bar,reorder bars a remove grid in horizontal grouped bar plot in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Hi this is my fake data:

```
 year<-c(rep(2010,3),rep(2011,3),rep(2012,3))
 value<-rnorm(9,10,5)
 nation<-rep(c("a","b","c"),3)
 fake<-data.frame(year,value,nation)
```

and this is code i already have:

```
ggplot(data=fake, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=nation)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.5, position=position_dodge())+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#006600", "#007f00","#009900"),name="Experimental\nCondition")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2010,2015,1),name="year")+
scale_y_continuous(breaks=F,name="value")+
theme(legend.title=element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(lineheight=0.9, face="bold"))+
ggtitle("arbitrary nation values in arbitrary years")+
coord_flip()
```

What i am trying to make is add values inside of each bar, remove grids in the background and reorder each single year from the highest to the lowest values,so the order of bars will be different in different years. And maybe one last thing is that little zero in the down left corner. In the first version of graph there was numbers on the X axis but i make desicion to remove them so i did but the zero persist. Its possible to erase it in some graphical editor but i guess it could be done throught code.

Thank you very much for every suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I almost got what you want, i'll send you this code. You could do something with the command `reorder()` to reorder the barplots by year.

```
ggplot(data=fake, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=nation)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.5, position=position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#006600", "#007f00","#009900"),name="Experimental\nCondition")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2010,2015,1),name="year")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=F,name="value")+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(lineheight=0.9, face="bold"))+
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, digits=2)), size = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), hjust=1)+
  ggtitle("arbitrary nation values in arbitrary years")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]